# PHP prepared mysqli statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been working with prepared statements for a while now and I have not come across any type of problems until today. I have the most bizarre problem ever. I have the following php code:

```
$email= $_GET['email'];
$confirmKey= $_GET['confirmKey'];
$checkKey = "select email from EmailConfirmations where email = ? and confirmKey = ? LIMIT 1;";
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($checkKey )){
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$confirmKey);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
        echo "Correct Key";

    }else
        echo "Incorrect Key";

    $stmt->close();


}else
    echo "Error: " . $stmt. "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
```

I always get an empty result set no matter what. I even checked if the parameters do have a value before being sent through and yes they do contain values before being sent through. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I ran the SQL script and it works fine. Please help

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, his syntax is fine

Comment: `var_dump($_GET['confirmKey']);` might contain characters that are being thrown out.

Comment: @Saty I removed the space, and no changes. Fred-ii- the confrimKey only has letters and numbers, no special characters. I even tried running the statement without the 'confirmKey' part, and still nothing

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sorry but I'm not seeing any mismatches?

Comment: @spongyboss then `var_dump();` your variables including the query and see what's going through or not. Check your column's type and length for it. Make sure it's long enough; that usually is a cause. Plus, use proper bracing as stated already; that could contribute to it also.

Comment: I suppose it depends on configuration - code on my platform setup like this throws warnings. Each `if` has an opening bracket, each `else` does not. I have deleted my other comments because I understand this works on certain platforms.

Comment: Single line `if` and `else` statements do not require curly braces. It *does* impact readability though.

Comment: The string that you use to build the prepared statement has a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the query. Can you remove it and try again?

Comment: Try this then `$numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows;` then `if($numberofrows ->num_rows > 0){` @spongyboss

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have tried that already, nothing bro. I even tried echoing `$result` to see if there is anything being returned, nothing. I do not know what I am doing wrong, been at this for 2 hours. Mjh i removed the semicolon and no changes still

Comment: @spongyboss I made a mistake, that should have read as `if($numberofrows > 0){`

Comment: @Fred-ii- lol, yeah, i picked that up before running it

Comment: also change `$stmt->execute();` to `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` see if it returns any errors. I know you already have it at the bottom, but try that method instead. You are using mysqli right to connect with and an object oriented method?

Comment: @Fred-ii- just tried it now, it runs without errors ey, think I should just use normal `mysqli_query()` for this, cause I have spent so much time on this already,